# Eclipse Github : Checkout conflict with Files not existing anymore

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm working with a friend and I've tried to pull a Git project with Eclipse.

As usually , Git tells me there is conflict with a jar file: `Checkout conflict with files...`

I deleted this file but for some reason it keeps telling me there is a conflict.

How can I have a conflict with a file that doesn't exist anymore and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

For Git, deleting a file is the same as editing a file : it is a change.

What you need to do is:

```
git reset HEAD <your jar file>
git checkout <your jar file>
```

- `git reset` will unstage the changes you might have added.
- `git checkout` will remove the changes you made to the jar file.

Then you will be able to pull.

You might want to use a [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file to avoid going through this process every time you pull. This file allows you to list files/directory that are ignored by Git.